# How do I make .bdf Format Bitmap Font work

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, unicode, fontconfig, bspwm

I'm using an Arch-based Linux distro.

Recently I started a New Ricing for my BSPWM. This time I want to use a bitmap font.

Well I would like a font with glyphs, so I chose Siji.

Previously I used some other bitmap fonts like Cozette, Scientifica, Tamsyn. And found that .otb-format bitmap fonts work fine and as expected. But .bdf (aka the only format Siji is available in) doesn't work. Even if I remove the `70-no-bitmap` file (removing that file made .otb fonts work but didn't do anything to .bdf).

Is there any other thing that I need to do to make it work?

I would like to know what could be the problem. What makes .bdf not work but makes .otb work? Is there a way to list all the glyphs in a grid so that I could copy the icons instead of the unicode (eg: `\uE297`)?

Also I need this so that I could configure Polybar and finish my rice (for any one who doesn't know ricing : its just a term for **customizing and making it better** and it's used for Linux/Unix customization).

Also is there a way to enter the Unicode (eg: "E0344") in Polybar configuration to display the icon (from one of the font that I have installed and declared in the config) instead of the Unicode text? When I use the Unicode reference (that i copied from material design icons website in Google fonts) and I paste it with `\u`, it doesn't work and displays `\uE322` instead of the icon.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple questions here and unfortunately I don't know the answer to all of them.

Why the `.bdf` font doesn't work, I don't know. For me, the [siji-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/siji-git/) package in the AUR works fine and it installs the bdf variant.

There is indeed a way to list all available glyphs in a grid: The [GNOME Character Map](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Gucharmap?action=show&redirect=Gucharmap) (or `gucharmap`). Be sure to select `View > Show only glyphs from this font`.
However, if siji does not show up in `fc-list`, it won't show up in gucharmap either.

And finally, polybar does not have a way to specify the hex code for a unicode code point at the time of writing. You have to copy-paste the glyphs directly.